# Calling prop and function in React-Native formik onBlur() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, formik

At the moment I am trying to call a function and the formikProps in my onBlur `TextInput` function at the same time.

```
<TextInput
   onBlur={() => {
      formikProps.handleBlur('password')
      setFocused(false)
   }
/>
```

**What I want to achieve:**

When I am leaving the **Textinput** I change the state of **isFocused** to true, because I want that the styles change at this moment. As well my Textinput should fire handleBlur(). But it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

this doesn't work for `multiline={true}`. And you should use the `onEndEditing` method instead of the `onBlur`

> onEndEditing?: function Callback that is called when text input ends.

```js
    onEndEditing={(e) => {
      formikProps.handleBlur('password')
      setFocused(false)
    }
```